# Format or change MySql database data to realpath using preg_match or preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing HTML data in MySQL database for some reason. how to get all image,css and jss file src from MySQL data and change it to realpath.
Like  to

Same as  to

And  to

Using preg_match or preg_replace in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this regex

```
/(?:src|href)="(.*?)"/g
```

Using preg_replace it will be something like this:

```
preg_replace('/(?:src|href)="(.*?)"/g', 'http:localhost/$1', 'Your field in database');
```

But test it not in production code, but in your local testing environment as I didn't test it.

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g', but using preg_replace('/(?:src|href)="(.*?)"/g', '"http:localhost/$1"', 'Your field in database'); it's work properly